# is there a way (clean or unclean) to eliminate a filestream data file on a production SQL Server database?

Tags: replication, availability-groups, mirroring, sql-server-2017, in-memory-database

Is there a way (clean or unclean) to eliminate a filestream data file on a production database?

I forced a garbage collection on an empty filestream :

```
sp_filestream_force_garbage_collection @dbname = N'DB' ,   @filename = N'db_mod';
```

I tried this and memory opt and filestream is't actually enabled on db

```
SELECT name, description FROM sys.dm_os_loaded_modules WHERE description = 'XTP Native DLL'
```

this script gives the files in db:

select sdf.name AS [FileName],
   size/128 AS [Size_in_MB],
   fg.name AS [File_Group_Name]
   FROM sys.database_files sdf
   INNER JOIN
   sys.filegroups fg
   ON sdf.data_space_id=fg.data_space_id

### FileName Size_in_MB File_Group_Name

db           7282        PRIMARY
   db_mod       1528        db_mod

Can I manage to eliminate this empty file and filegroup that prevents me from using db mirroring?

of course I tried

```
-- Remove the File
```

ALTER DATABASE db REMOVE FILE db_mod1 ;
-- Remove the Filegroup
ALTER DATABASE db REMOVE FILEGROUP db_mod ;

I get the error:

> Msg 41802, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot drop the last memory-optimized container 'db_mod1'.

Comment: What version of SQL is this? Mirroring has log since been deprecated.

Comment: sql server 2017 CU 12 , what would you suggest instead of mirroring?

Comment: Please add this label of this Version in your question. Also look up The official Microsoft documentation for replication transaction log shipping, replication and High availability alwaysOn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be clear, the FILESTREAM and In-Memory OLTP features are completely separate, and not compatible. Even though In-Memory OLTP uses some components of FILESTREAM, the FILESTREAM feature does *not* have to be enabled to use In-Memory OLTP, and memory-optimized tables are not able to be used with the FILESTREAM feature.

According to the error you received, you're trying to remove the memory-optimized filegroup, which is not possible.

What does the following query return?

```
 SELECT *
FROM [InMemTest2].sys.database_files
INNER JOIN [InMemTest2].sys.filegroups ON database_files.data_space_id = filegroups.data_space_id
WHERE filegroups.type = 'FX'
```

Comment: this:file_id file_guid type type_desc data_space_id name physical_name state state_desc size max_size growth is_media_read_only
65537 1F0FEE91-0EB8-498D-AD49-03500FFD5388 2 FILESTREAM 2 db_mod1 E:\Database\SQLServer\DATA\db_mod1 0 ONLINE 195593 -1 0 0

Comment: If you have a filegroup of type 'FX', then you have a memory-optimized filegroup for that database, and as I said, it's not possible to remove it.

Comment: what would you suggest instead of mirroring? I have sql server 2017 CU 12

Comment: Why not use AGs? They are supported with memory-optimized databases, but they are potentially more complex. But you could do Basic AG, and even one (maybe) that is "clusterless". But you'd have to research it to see if it would work in your environment, and BAGs are not readable on the secondary.